# Function to check if any combination of numbers in a vector will add up to an int?

Tags: c++

To start with, I'm looking for something simple and easy to understand rather than the most efficient.

I am trying to create a function that will take in a `vector`, and an `int`. The function should return `true` if any numbers in the vector can add up to the int.

The vector will start with the numbers `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` in it, and throughout the program numbers will be removed. There will be no duplicates of numbers.

The `int` can be any number from 2 through 12.

Some examples:

- `vector = { 2,3,4,5 } int = 7;` function returns `true` because `3 + 4 = 7`.
- `vector = { 1,5,8 } int = 7;` function returns `false` because none of these numbers can add to 7.
- `vector = { 3,6 } int = 3;` function returns `true` because `3 = 3`.
- `vector = { 5 } int = 2;` function returns `false` because five cannot add to two.

This is the very last function I need to finish a game I am working on. I feel like I'm missing an easy solution, but I'm not sure. Can anyone show me how to do this, or point me in the right direction of how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can your vector contain negatives?

Comment: Do you know if all the numbers in the vector are unique?  If you have duplicates, it makes the problem somwhat harder.

Comment: They will all be unique, and the only numbers possible will be 1-10. Thanks for the response!

Comment: In your first example, 2+5 also equals 7. Is it supposed to short-circuit once it finds a combination that adds up to what you want? How does 3+6 = 3? You need to better define your rules.

Comment: And are the elements ordered as in your examples?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to reorder the numbers in the vector?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Given the previous answers, at most 10 elements.

Comment: Can you use the same vector element twice?

Comment: @0A0D, sorry for not being clear. The Vector that includes 3 and 6 will work because the 3 adds up to 3. Any numbers in the vector can add up to the int. It does not need to be all of them.

Comment: @sfrabbit, Yes, the numbers in the vector will always be in numerical order.

Comment: @celtshk The numbers will always be positive. 
Thanks everyone for the responses!

Comment: @WouterH To be clear, you are asking if for example a vector contains just 3, could you use the three twice to add up to 6? If that is what you meant, then no, the function should not allow that. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the additional information in the comments, the following function should do (I'm assuming the same number cannot be used twice in the sum):

```
typedef std::vector<int>::iterator iter;
bool contains_sum(iter begin, iter end, int sum)
{
  while (begin != end)
  {
    --end;
    if (*end > sum)
      continue;
    if (contains_sum(begin, end, sum - *end))
      return true;
  }
  return sum == 0;
}
```

Comment: @piotr: Can you please give valid test data where this function gives an incorrect answer? I don't seem to be able to find such a test case. Nor do I see any problem in the logic.

Comment: I checked and seems that it works. my apologies. I will upvote as soon as my vote is unlocked.

Comment: @stefanbachert: No it doesn't. Note that `end` is decremented *before* the recursive call is made.

Comment: However, there's still an optimization which could be done, since the numbers guaranteed to be positive: If `*end` is larger than `sum`, we already know that it cannot be part of the sum, so we don't need the recursive call in that case (not that it would make a noticeable difference for just up to 10 values anyway). I'll edit that improvement in.

Comment: upvoted, quite elegant solution: We were discussing with colleagues if there could be a way to formally proove correctness of such a recursive algorithm, what do you think?

Comment: Well, if the sequence is empty, the algorithm is obviously right. If the sequence is *not* empty, there are two cases: Either there's a set involving the last element giving the sum, or there isn't. There is such a set involving the last element iff there is a set of the previous elements giving the sum *minus* the last element (the recursive call). If there's such a set, we are ready. Otherwise we have to test if there's a set giving the sum *without* the last element, i.e. going to the next iteration of the loop. I guess from that reasoning a formal proof could be built.

Comment: And how about when you design a recursive algorithm for a new problem, it, will you think about it bottom up or top down?

Comment: I'm a little confused by this since I'm new to programming and to C++. 
What would I pass in for begin and end for the first call? I understand that it's recursive and will call its self after that. If you can give me an example I can 'probably' step through this with a debugger and get a better sense on how it's solving the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: @piotr: I'll think about it in whatever way I feel most comfortable with. Which depends very much on the problem at hand. Note that how you arrive at the algorithm is not necessarily the same way how you verify it after you've found it. Indeed, the very fact that I'm iterating on the end instead of the beginning is because originally I intended to make use of the fact that the numbers are ordered — a fact which I ended up not using at all.

Comment: @user1308743: If the `vector<int>` containing the list of numbers is called `numbers`, you'll call it as `bool result = contains_sum(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), intended_sum);`

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this a case of the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)?

See also: [subset sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

Comment: Yes, but this is a comment not an answer as it is written.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to find all possible combinations and then check if any of those have the right sum. A double-recursive function can make the check.

```
bool canFormSum(vector<int>::iterator rest, vector<int>::iterator end, 
  int sumSoFar, int targetSum)
{
  if(rest == end) return false;
  if(sumSoFar + *rest == targetSum) return true;
  if(canFormSum(rest + 1, end, sumSoFar, targetSum)) return true;
  if(sumSoFar + *rest > targetSum) return false;
  return canFormSum(rest + 1, end, sumSoFar + *rest, targetSum);
}
```

It's a nice example of recursive calculation - but for anything but small vectors it has horrible performance.

Answer (score 0):

For the general cases (size of vector > 10),

Let `f({a, b, c, d, ...}, e)` be the result of whether any number in the set `{a, b, c, d, ...}` be equal to `e`.

Observe that, if `e = x + y + z + ...`, then either (1) `a` is in the set of `{x, y, z, ...}`, or (2) `a` is not in the set of `{x, y, z, ...}`. That means, we have the **recursive definition**:

```
f({a, etc...}, e) = f({etc...}, e-a) || f({etc...}, e)
```

And obviously, if the sum is 0, the relation is always true by not including any element from the set:

```
f({...}, 0) = true
```

and if the set is empty and the sum is nonzero, the relation is always false:

```
f({}, e) = false (if e != 0)
```

These are the **base cases** of the recursion.

---

**Edit:** See also the [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) for further discussion.

Comment: sure, recursion. But what is your solution? Or do you showed us, there will be a solution? Mathematician?

Comment: @stefanbachert: Do your own homework ☺. That's only 10 lines of code. (Without considering dynamic programming mess since OP doesn't aim for efficiency.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to try all possible combination until you found a solution. SUch problems would be good for the language "prolog". So we have to simulate backtracking.
this code is in the end c.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int check (int* in, int sum) {
  while (1) {
    int act = *in++;
    if (act == 0) return 0;
    int rest = sum - act;
    if (rest > 0) {   // test in the order of expected likelyhoods
      if (1 == check (in, rest)) return 1;     // found
    }
//  if (rest < 0) return 0; // minor optimization, valid if list is ordered ascendant
    if (rest == 0) return 1;  // found;
  }
//return -1; // only necessary on poor compilers
}

void pr (int* in, int sum) {
    int res = check (in, sum);

    while (*in) {
      printf ("%d ", *in ++);
    }
    if (res == 0) {
        printf(" != %d\n", sum);
    } else {
        printf(" == %d\n", sum);
    }
}

int main () {

    int p1[] = {2,3,4,5, 0};
    pr (p1, 7);

    int p2[] = {1,5,8, 0};
    pr (p2, 7);

    int p3[] = {3,6, 0};
    pr (p3, 3);

    int p4[] = {5, 0};
    pr (p4, 2);

    int p5[] = {1, 100, 6, 0};
    pr (p5, 7);

    return 0;

}
```

proven to run

```
2 3 4 5  == 7
1 5 8  != 7
3 6  == 3
5  != 2
1 100 6  == 7
```

Comment: this approach will also work with duplicate numbers. And the order don't care, too

Comment: *in ++   not nice without parens and space

Comment: As I said: prooven not to run:  1 100 6  != 7     In a more constructive manner, do you know a formal method to proove or disproove that a recursive function is correct?

Comment: I think celtschk is more elegant though

Comment: "You have to find all possible combination" No, you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Just to compare my (C) solution with celtschk (c++) solution. (Basically compared the approach, not the languages)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int counter = 0;

typedef std::vector<int>::iterator iter;
bool contains_sum(iter begin, iter end, int sum)
{
  counter ++;
  while (begin != end)
  {
    --end;
    if (contains_sum(begin, end, sum - *end))
      return true;
  }
  return sum == 0;
}


int main () {
    vector<int> data;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i ++) {
        data.push_back(i);
    }
    int target = 77;

    if (contains_sum (data.begin(), data.end(), target)) {
      cout << "possible\n" << counter;
    } else {
      cout << "not possible\n << counter";
    }

}
```

output

```
possible
268304387
```

Means nearly 270 million calls of recursive method

Now my approach

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int counter;

int check (int* in, int sum) {
  counter ++;
  while (1) {
    int act = *in++;
    if (act == 0) return 0;
    int rest = sum - act;
    if (rest == 0) return 1;  // found;
    if (rest > 0) {
      if (1 == check (in, rest)) return 1;     // found
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

void pr (int* in, int sum) {
    counter = 0;
    int res = check (in, sum);

    while (*in) {
      printf ("%d ", *in ++);
    }
    if (res == 0) {
        printf(" != %d %d\n", sum, counter);
    } else {
        printf(" == %d %d\n", sum, counter);
    }
}

int main () {
    int p0[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,
                11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
                21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
                0};
    pr (p0, 77);    

    int p1[] = {2,3,4,5, 0};
    pr (p1, 7);

    int p2[] = {1,5,8, 0};
    pr (p2, 7);

    int p3[] = {3,6, 0};
    pr (p3, 3);

    int p4[] = {5, 0};
    pr (p4, 2);

    int p5[] = {1, 100, 6, 0};
    pr (p5, 7);

    return 0;

}
```

and this is the output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30  == 77 22
2 3 4 5  == 7 4
1 5 8  != 7 4
3 6  == 3 1
5  != 2 1
1 100 6  == 7 2
```

Ups, just 22 iterations!
Anyone may decide which approach to consider more "elegant"

Comment: After celtschk optimization both approaches calls nearly the same times it function